# Declaration of Anonymous types List

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, anonymous-types

Is there any way to declare a list object of anonymous type. I mean

```
List<var> someVariable = new List<var>();
someVariable.Add(
             new{Name="Krishna", 
                 Phones = new[] {"555-555-5555", "666-666-6666"}}
                );
```

This is because I need to create a collection at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand what the point of a List with anonymous types is.

Comment: There are some use cases for them. An example is when you need to mix an LINQ-to-SQL query with a memory-backed collection.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It involves a bit of hackery but it can be done.

```
static List<T> CreateListFromSingle<T>(T value) {
  var list = new List<T>();
  list.Add(value);
  return list;
}

var list = CreateListFromSingle(
   new{Name="Krishna", 
                 Phones = new[] {"555-555-5555", "666-666-6666"}}
                );
```

Comment: Ack. This is clever, and it works, but I'd be so mad if any of my developers ever did this in real work...  +1 for the nice trickery, though.

Comment: @Reed, agreed it's painful to look at but it work

Comment: no offense, but I hope he doesn't use this code.. :D

Comment: Nice trick, I have never seen this before.

Comment: @Krishna: For good reason, too ;)

Comment: How is this any worse than using anonymous types in LINQ?

Comment: @RobertDavis because you should be using Eric's answer which is as simple as a `var` and a `ToList()` !

Comment: I'm guessing that a lot of the objection to this code is due to a lack of understanding of social dynamics and how we humans tend to jump on bandwagons of conventional opinion touting.  It's not any worse than anon. types in Linq!

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Which part would you hate for your developers to implement? The `CreateListFromSingle` part or using that function with an anonymous type?

Comment: Or more simply and concise (assuming you can use System.Linq namespace)

`((new[] { new { /* fields */ } }).ToList()`

Answer (score 87):

*How about dynamic?*

```
List<dynamic> dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();


dynamicList.Add(new { Name = "Krishna",  Phones = new[] { "555-555-5555", "666-666-6666" } });
```

Comment: Thanks @JaiKannah, definitely should be the answer for .NET 4.x.  Brings us much closer to the flexibility of PHP arrays without the hackery.

Comment: This is a much better solution as opposed to the others...

Comment: `dynamic` = no intellisense. Thanks, but no. Even ugly tuple's `Item1` is better.

Answer (score 55):

You can make a list like this, but you'll again have to use some serious hackery, and you'll have to use some "type by example" situations.  For example:

```
// create the first list by using a specific "template" type.
var list = new [] { new { Name="", Phones=new[] { "" } } }.ToList();

// clear the list.  The first element was just an example.
list.Clear();

// start adding "actual" values.
list.Add(new { Name = "Krishna", Phones = new[] { "555-555-5555", "666-666-6666" } });
```

Comment: Okay - this is, again, clever, and horrifying to watch at the same time... +1

Comment: Clever, haven't seen that inline trick before

Comment: Thank you, I will save it for the future.

Comment: @kervin, in this case I'm fairly certain the compiler does.  If you create two anonymous types which have the same named parameters of the same type there will be a single anonymous type generated.  In any case if it doesn't a compile error will be issued for this code

Comment: @JaredPar: you're correct.  They would be the same type.  Thanks.

Comment: You can declare it in one line: new [] { new { Name="", Phones=new[] { "" } } }.Where(x => false).ToList();

Answer (score 28):

In general you can use the (arguably bad-smelling) cast by example trick others have mentioned to create instances of any generic type parameterized with an anonymous type for the type argument. However, for `List<T>` there is a slightly less gross way to do it:

```
var array = new[] {
  new {  
    Name="Krishna",  
    Phones = new[] {"555-555-5555", "666-666-6666"}
  }
};
var list = array.ToList();
```

Your sketch of a proposed syntax is similar to a feature we did not implement for C# 3 or 4, but we considered. We call the feature "mumble types", and it would go something like this:

```
List<?> myList = new List<?>() {
  new {  
    Name="Krishna",  
    Phones = new[] {"555-555-5555", "666-666-6666"}
  }
};
```

We call it "mumble types" because of course you'd read it "myList is a new list of hrmmf".  :-)

The idea is that the compiler would look at the initializers and do its best to figure out what the type could possibly be, just the same way as how "var" means "look at the initializer and figure out what the type of the variable is".  Whether we'd use "var" as the "mumble" or "?" (which is similar to what Java does in a related feature), or something else is an open question.

In any event, I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for this feature if I were you. It hasn't made the cut for several language versions so far, but it will stay on the list of possibilities for a while longer I think. If, hypothetically speaking, we were to be designing future versions of the language. Which we might or might not be. Remember, Eric's musings about future versions of C# are for entertainment purposes only.

Comment: +1 for the good name ("mumble types")
and 
+1 for not implementing it.  I would imagine the cost to do this isn't cheap, and the work around for it is pretty easy, and more maintainable...

Answer (score 16):

You can't make a collection of an anonymous type like this.

If you need to do this, you'll need to either use `List<object>`, or make a custom class or struct for your type.

---

Edit:

I'll rephrase this:

Although, technically, it's possible to make a list of an anonymous type, I would strongly recommend never doing this.  There is pretty much always a better approach, as doing this is just making code that is nearly unmaintainable.  I highly recommend making a custom type to hold your values instead of using anonymous types.

A custom type will have all of the same capabilities (since anonymous types are defined, by the compiler, at compile time), but will be much more understandable by the developer who follows you...

---

And just to play, too, here's my entry for "code I'd never actually want to use in the real world":

```
var customer = new { Name = "Krishna", Phones = new[] { "555-555-5555", "666-666-6666" } };
var someVariable = new[]{1}.Select(i => customer).ToList();
```

Comment: Agreed. I think a good rule of thumb is that if you're concerned about the type of an anonymous type object, then you're doing ( or getting ready to ) do something wrong.

Comment: +1 it takes half a second to create a custom type and it saves hours of debugging unmanageable/confusing code.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an approach that is somewhat cleaner than many of the other suggestions:

```
var list = Enumerable.Repeat(new { Name = "", Phones = new[] { "" } }, 0)
               .ToList();

// ...
list.Add(new { Name = "Krishna", 
               Phones = new[] { "555-555-5555", "666-666-6666" } });
```

Comment: very elegant solution - thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 9):

I spent quite a lot of time trying to find a way to save myself some time using a list of anonymous types, then realised it was probably quicker just to use a private class inside the current class...

```
private class Lookup {
    public int Index;
    public string DocType;
    public string Text;
}
private void MyMethod() {
    List<Lookup> all_lookups = new List<Lookup> {
        new Lookup() {Index=4, DocType="SuperView", Text="SuperView XML File"},
        new Lookup() {Index=2, DocType="Word", Text="Microsoft Word Document"}
    };
    // Use my all_lookups variable here...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. Maybe in C# 4 using the dynamic keyword?

Comment: you can, but it wouldn't be a good idea. this is a good example of why some people believe the `dynamic` keyword will be abused.