# Anonymous Type, Enumerator and Lambda expression

Tags: c#

With :

```
    var Foo = new[]{ new {Something = 321}};
```

Why can I do (compile) :

```
    Console.WriteLine( Foo[0].Something );
```

but not :

```
     Foo.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Something));
```

Comment: What actually is the compile error?

Comment: Connot Resolve Symbol Something

Comment: It is not the foreach who generate the error but I cannot access to the member of x

Comment: @ChristopheDebove: The ForEach *does* generate a compiler error. Are you sure that this is the code you really used?

Comment: @Heinzi you're right I restart VS and it claim me the compilation error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Array` only have a static [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) method:

```
var Foo = new[] { new { Something = 321 } };
Array.ForEach(Foo, x => Console.WriteLine(x.Something));
```

compiles and works.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
 Foo.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Something));
```

instead, as the ForEach extension is only available for lists

**EDIT**: tested and works.

**EDIT2**: A few workarounds to make an "anonymous list"

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327594/declaration-of-anonymous-types-list)
[This blog post](http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-create-generic-list-of-anonymous.html)
[Another blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/08/17/defining-lists-of-anonymous-types.aspx)

Comment: It is not the foreach who generate the error but I cannot access to the member of x

Comment: @ChristopheDebove I just tried my snippet in a test project and it compiles and executes as expected. Which error are you having now?

Comment: So it is not possible to have a List of anonymouse Type? without using ToList?

Comment: After a bit of googling, it does not seem to be possible. I'll add a few workarounds.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove, if you don't want to use linq then use the other answr you got from namesv use `Array.ForEach`. Note it's a static method not an instance method.

Comment: ok it derive my first quesion. but the former explains the latter.

Comment: it seem's KIRILL OSENKOV post is more or less what you explain to me.   Ok, I will sleep less stupid tonight