# Make our own List<string, string, string>

Tags: c#, .net, list

Can we make our own `List<string, string, string>` in C#.NET? I need to make a list having 3 different strings as a single element in the list.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can certainly create your own class called `List` with three generic type parameters. I would *strongly* discourage you from doing so though. It would confuse the heck out of anyone using your code.

Instead, *either* use `List<Tuple<string, string, string>>` (if you're using .NET 4, anyway) or (preferrably) create your own class to encapsulate those three strings in a meaningful way, then use `List<YourNewClass>`.

Creating your own class will make it much clearer when you're writing and reading the code - by giving names to the three different strings involved, everyone will know what they're meant to mean. You can also give more behaviour to the class as and when you need to.

Comment: how fetch back the values from the List of Tuple created ?

Comment: @HotTester : what do you mean by fetch back the values?

Comment: @HotTester: Use the properties of `Tuple<,,>` - but it'll be a lot less readable than creating your own class.

Comment: yourlist[listItemIndex].(will open for you a list of property of how many items inside the tuple you have added).

Comment: @Jon thanks for reply. I have one more query. Can we give name to the items in the Tuple, like Tuple<string name, string empCode, string grade) ? For when we are fetching items from Tuple it gives name as item1, item2, item3 for the Tuple<string,string,string>. Can we give name to this "item1", "item2" ,"item3" ?

Comment: @HotTester: Yes, by creating your own type.  If you are dead set against creating a new type, you could [(ab)use cast by example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2327612/18192)

Comment: @HotTester: That's exactly the point of creating your own type (and potentially giving it behaviour, etc). You can't change the properties of `Tuple`, but you can create your own classes with your own properties...

Answer (score 12):

You can use a [Tuple](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/tuple-in-c-4-0/) to achieve that.

For example:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string,string,string>>();
```

to iterate over the values you *may want* to do a simple:

```
    list.ForEach(x=>{
     //x is a Tuple
    });
```

or to **find** some specific tupple, you *may want* to do the folowing:

```
     var list = new List<Tuple<string,string,string>>{
        new Tuple<string,string,string>("Hello", "Holla", "Ciao"),
        new Tuple<string,string,string>("Buy", "--", "Ciao")
     };

     list.Where(x=>x.Item2 == "--");
```

This will return the last Tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list of [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).  Like so:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, string>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
var ls= new List<Tuple<string,string,string>>();
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend this solution

```
 public class MyCustomClass
    {
        public string MyString1 { get; set; }
        public string MyString2 { get; set; }
        public string MyString3 { get; set; }
    }

    class MyApp
    {
        public MyApp()
        {
            List<MyCustomClass> customList = new List<MyCustomClass>();
            customList.Add(new MyCustomClass
            {
                MyString1 = "Hello",
                MyString2 = "Every",
                MyString3 = "Body",
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
var tuple = Tuple.Create("a", "b", "c");
list.Add(tuple);
```

For more information, look in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.tuple.aspx).

Comment: Thank link is very... Russian.  Good thing i can read "Россия (Pусский)".

Comment: For those that can't read Russian... ;)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.tuple.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about making a `List<Tuple<string, string, string>>` ?

A better idea might be though, if each of the strings has a specific meaning, to put them all into a class and then create a List of that.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone tried `dynamic` ?

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(new { Name = "SampleN", Address = "SampleA", Email = "SampleE" });

var name = list[0].Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly this does't work. The best you can do is to create a List of Lists, or utilise some form of implementation of the IDictionary interface.

Although, that said, if you have three items of data which belong together in this manner, it's probably worthwhile creating a class to contain them.

That would then give you the opportunity to pass a List around your application and assign meaningful names to each data item. Never underestimate the power of readability six months down the line.

Comment: Actually scratch that, @Tigran's solution is not only better than mine, it taught me something I didn't know.

Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

You may define a List and implement the needed interfaces(such as IList). Codes blow.

```
public class List<T1, T2, T3> : IList
{

    #region IList Members

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsFixedSize
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection Members

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

However, `List<Tuple<string,string,string>>` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Listt< T, T1, T2>
    {
         public Listt()
        {

        }
        public void Add(T item, T1 item1, T2 item3)
        {

        }
    }


public partial class MyApp : Window
{

 public MyApp()

 {

  InitializeComponent();

     Listt<string, string, string> customList = new Listt<string, string, string>();
     customList.Add("we","are","here");

  }
}
```