# Get all Dictionary values using linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# List:

```
private List<Tuple<string, string>> _list1 = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
string keyToLookFor;
string valueToLookFor;
```

I want to search this List using LINQ to check if first a certain key already exists and if so does its value match valueToLookFor.

```
List.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("1", "data1"));
List.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("2", "data2"));
List.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("2", "data3"));
List.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("3", "data3"));
```

So for this example  I want to find is "2" exists and check if its data matches what I'm looking for.
How can I do this in LINQ?

Comment: why not create a Class I think in your case it would be much easier.. also have you done any google searches on how to read values from a Tuple using Linq.. if you want to do this with a class refer to this previous posting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597629/make-our-own-liststring-string-string

Comment: Dictionary<T,T> sounds like what you're looking for

Comment: Can a Dictionary have non-unique keys??

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @HarryBoy no, it can't, but you can always have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Answer (score 3):

The key in a List of tuple isnt unique, first you might want to use a

```
Dictionary<string, string>()
```

but if you want to keep the list

```
_list1.Where( t => t.Item1 == keyToLookFor && t.Item2 == valueToLookFor );
```

Comment: I need it to be not unique that why I'm not using a Dictionary.

Comment: @ I thought HashSet was the only class that required distinct values

Comment: You'll get an ArgumentException if you try to add a duplicate key to a Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C# 6 (and each tuple has an unique **key value**):

```
bool exists = _list1.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Item1 == keyToLookFor)?.Item2 == valueToLookFor;
```

---

If your list can have more than one tuple with the same **key value**:

```
bool exists = _list1.Any(t => t.Item1 == keyToLookFor && t.Item2 == valueToLookFor);
```

Comment: What does the ? Do?

Comment: @Edward It's a [Null-Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

Comment: So you need that to return false if there are no matches?

Comment: @Edward That's right. If there are no matches, `SingleOrDefault` will return null, and `exists` would be `null == valueToLookFor`, which is `false`

Comment: I guess what I am asking is without that question mark  would it throw an error?

Comment: @Edward Yes, it'd throw a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 3):

HashSet would do the trick (it can handle duplicates). It is also worth noting that HashSets were designed for high-performance set operations. If your list1 is very large and/or you will be performing frequent lookups on it, you should be using a HashSet.

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> list1 = new List<System.Tuple<string, string>>();
list1.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("1", "data1"));
list1.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("2", "data2"));
list1.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("2", "data3"));
list1.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("2", "data3")); //duplicate
list1.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("3", "data3"));

var hs  = new HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>(list1);

var toCheck = new Tuple<string,string>("2","data3");
Console.WriteLine(hs.Contains(toCheck)); //True
toCheck = new Tuple<string,string>("2","data7");
Console.WriteLine(hs.Contains(toCheck)); //False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a dictionary instead all you describe is built in

```
Dictionary<string,string> _list1 = new Dictionary<string,string>();
if(_list1.containsKey(keyToLookFor)) {
   return _list1[keyToLookFor] == valueToLookFor;
}
```