# Declaration of list of anonymous types

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know if the question is properly formatted but what I'm trying to do is to create the `var reservations` outside the `using` loop but don't know how to initialize it.

This code works :

```
using (MainContextDB db = new MainContextDB())
{
    var reservations = (from c in db.Reservations select new { c.CustAcctNo, c.ReservNo, c.ReservStatus }).ToList();
}
```

Any attempt to declare the `var` outside the loop will trigger an error:

> Cannot convert List to List

I've tried:

```
var reservations = new List<dynamic>();
var reservations = new List<object>();
```

---

This code works, but requires to retrieve all columns, which is not what I want:

```
List<Reservation> reservations = new List<Reservation>();
using (MainContextDB db = new MainContextDB())
{
    reservations = db.Reservations.ToList();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaration of Anonymous types List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327594/declaration-of-anonymous-types-list)

Comment: The whole point of a `using` statement is to add proper cleanup in a `catch` block. If you implement a proper `try` and `catch` block that takes the functionality of a `using`, you don't need a `using`. This should free you to think about the problem differently. I recognize that the scope of the `var reservations` still has to be tied to the scope of the `try` (since otherwise, how could the `catch` have scope access to dispose of the object properly), but perhaps that will help you find a different solution.

Comment: @ErikE +1 Agree.This is the solution that I end up using.

Comment: @SimonC You are right but look at the second example in the answer here, it is not in the other link

Comment: possible duplicate of [A generic list of anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
var reservations = new []
{
    new { CustAcctNo = "", ReservNo = "", ReservStatus = "" }
}.ToList();

using (MainContextDB db = new MainContextDB())
{
    reservations = (
        from c in db.Reservations
        select new
        {
            c.CustAcctNo, c.ReservNo, c.ReservStatus
        }).ToList();
}
```

You just have to make sure you match the types on the members of your anonymous class.

---

The other option is to add a reference to the Microsoft Reactive Framework Team's "Interactive Extensions". They have a nice `Using` method for enmerables that lets you do this:

```
var reservations = 
    EnumerableEx
        .Using(
            () => new MainContextDB(),
            db =>
                from c in db.Reservations
                select new
                {
                    c.CustAcctNo, c.ReservNo, c.ReservStatus
                })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I've already seen the first example before, but the second one is, in my opinion, currently, the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok that ended up being a really interesting question-

I know that anonymous types aren't supposed to leave the method context, hadn't really thought about them leaving scope though...

I see a few possible options...

- Do something hackey - Two anon types with the same signature share the same type, so you could coerce it into accepting a prototype and go from there. (converting into a list is difficult but doable in generics... see the link posted by simo)
- Move the operations into your using context which I know isn't ideal
- Manually dispose the context
- Handle the items as dynamic
- You could substitute a custom type or a tuple for the anonymous type

Hope that helps, I'm somewhat suprised there isn't a straightforward way to do this if you are remaining inside a method scope.

Comment: + 1 for your suggestions and comments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I would use none of the below approaches in performance-sensitive code*.

Having said that, I am seeing a very simple solution here which can also be applied when you're dealing with types other than `List<T>`. A bit of type inference gets the job done:

```
private T InvokeAndReturn<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    return func();
}
```

Usage:

```
// reservations is List<'a>.
var reservations = this.InvokeAndReturn(() =>
{
    using (var db = new MainContextDB())
    {
        return db.Reservations
            .Select(c => new { c.CustAcctNo, c.ReservNo, c.ReservStatus })
            .ToList();
    }
});
```

**Fresh edit**

Just had to use this in my own code and opted for an `IDisposable`-aware alternative instead:

```
TReturn Using<TDisposable, TReturn>(TDisposable disposable, Func<TDisposable, TReturn> func)
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    try
    {
        return func(disposable);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var reservations = Using(new MainContextDB(), db =>
{
    return db.Reservations
        .Select(c => new { c.CustAcctNo, c.ReservNo, c.ReservStatus })
        .ToList();
});
```

Or an even shorter version

```
var reservations = Using(new MainContextDB(), db =>
    db.Reservations
        .Select(c => new { c.CustAcctNo, c.ReservNo, c.ReservStatus })
        .ToList()
);
```