# C# "Anonymous" type of List stored inside a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-mvc-5, anonymous-types

I'm coming to the conclusion this may be impossible, but I figured I'd ask here before giving up entirely.  What I am looking for is something similar to this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<T>> FilterLists { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to store any amount of lists that may be needed and then be able to find them by a string Key 'index'.

The reason I need it like this is because of where this has to be stored due to certain constraints, and it would be impossible to type the List as anything specific because it can't see the object type that I want to put in there.  Even if I could see the object type, that reduces its re-usability in other projects where what someone might want to put in there could be constructed differently anyway and I am trying to make this as reusable as possible.

I had found this post: [Declaration of Anonymous types List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327594/declaration-of-anonymous-types-list), but this doesn't quite work with what I'm trying to do.

Also, this has to go in an Interface class, so it's simply a definition.

**Usage Explanation**:
This is specifically for use in paginating results in an MVC5 application.  The result list is returned, but I also want dropdown filters in certain header columns (like you would see in Excel filtering of columns).

I am trying to avoid the use of the ViewBag as much as possible for a few reasons.  I don't like using it.
My "Pagination" code is in a project known as Common at a level to make it accessible to both my Web project and my Service project (Business Logic layer).  The Models and ViewModels I am using are stored in Service, so I can't have Common referencing Service because Service already references Common for the custom IPagedList construct used to define a list of objects that will be paginated.  IPagedData contains a bunch of properties for filtering, sorting and paginating the result set.  A LINQ extension (.ToPageList) was created to facilitate these operations on the data.  There are several objects involved with this process, but I will at least post the IPagedData (where I want this dictionary to go).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GameKeyExchange.Common.Pagination
{
    public interface IPagedData
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<T>> FilterLists { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores pagination and sort information.
        /// </summary>
        PageSortCriteria Criteria { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total number of subsets within the superset.
        /// </summary>
        int PageCount { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total number of objects contained within the superset.
        /// </summary>
        int TotalItemCount { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Zero-based index of this subset within the superset.
        /// </summary>
        int PageIndex { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// One-based index of this subset within the superset.
        /// </summary>
        int PageNumber { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Maximum size any individual subset.
        /// </summary>
        int PageSize { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this is NOT the first subset within the superset.
        /// </summary>
        bool HasPreviousPage { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this is NOT the last subset within the superset.
        /// </summary>
        bool HasNextPage { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this is the first subset within the superset.
        /// </summary>
        bool IsFirstPage { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if this is the last subset within the superset.
        /// </summary>
        bool IsLastPage { get; }
    }
}
```

The code implementation would ideally look like this in my Service:

```
var list = data.ClaimedKeys.Where(m => m.UserId == UserId).Select(m => new ClaimedKeysViewModel()
{
    KeyTypeId = m.GameKey.GameKeyGroup.KeyTypeId,
    PlatformId = m.GameKey.GameKeyGroup.PlatformId,

    Value = m.GameKey.Value,
    KeyType = m.GameKey.GameKeyGroup.KeyType.Name,
    Game = m.GameKey.GameKeyGroup.Game.Name,
    Platform = m.GameKey.GameKeyGroup.Platform.Name,
    Expiration = m.GameKey.GameKeyGroup.Expiration
})

list.FilterLists.Add("KeyTypeFilter", list.Select(m => new List<SelectListModel>()
{
    Value = m.KeyTypeId,
    Text = m.KeyType
});

list.FilterLists.Add("PlatformFilter", list.Select(m => new List<SelectListModel>()
{
    Value = m.PlatformId,
    Text = m.Platform
});

list.OrderBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", sort, order))
    .ToPagedList<ClaimedKeysViewModel>(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

This way, I can get the list of data to paginate in the service, build my pagination, and also include any number of Filter Lists which gets sent back to the controller.  The controller receives this: IPageList which is the list of data, including these extra properties for sorting and filtering.  The reason they are passed down with the list of data is so that when resorting by clicking a header or changing the page, you know exactly which page you are on and the current status of your sorting for when it fetches each page or resorts.

Otherwise, I have to make a secondary call to the database to build my Filters and send them down as ViewBag objects.  Also, because the initial View and the Refresh Method (which is used after the initial load for resorting or navigating pages) I have to have the same code in both Methods to build the lists.  If I can have it in the service method that generates the list, it only has to be done there; the same method that is already being called in both controller methods anyway.

Hopefully that clarifies the use case better.

Comment: Show us how you would like to **use** that. BTW if you add a generic parameter `T` to your interface (or - giving up with good compile-time checks - if you avoid generics all together - in favor to untyped lists, objects or dynamics - if lists aren't homogeneous inside same `interface`)...

Comment: `List<object>` can hold anonymous types, but you cannot do much with them without reflection or something. `List<dynamic>` can hold them and allow you to duck-type the members, but shifts a lot of potential problems to the runtime. My honest answer? This seems like a really bad design / solution to whatever the problem is.

Comment: The only answer you'll find to this question is add a type parameter to your class/interface, as others have mentioned. It would help to see how you plan on using it.

Comment: @Brandon exactly ! He could get much more help if he shows how he exactly intends to use it.

Comment: Updated with further explanations of my intended usage.

Comment: @RobertBurke the code is very ambiguous and has a lot of compile errors, how is your the variable list is an IEnumerable<ClaimedKeysViewModel>, so how would it have the property FilterLists !?. Your LINQ is incorrect in the following lines also.

also where is IPagedData used ? i can't see that.

Comment: @SirajMansour Like I said, there are several classes and interfaces involved with this.  I only posted the one where I want the Dictionary to go.  I'd have to post 6 other classes for this all to work.  Should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the type T at compile time, then why do you need generics in the first place ?

If you only mean to re-use it in different projects, then add a generic constraint to your interface :

```
public interface IFilters<T>
{
    Dictionary<string, List<T>> FilterLists { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe T is the wrong thing to use there.  I was just using it as a placeholder to mean something dynamic that we don't know what will be there until runtime.  The Interface itself has no reference to a <T>.  I just need something to go in between `List<>` that will allow me to populate it with a List of some unknown, incoming object when implemented elsewhere in the code.

Comment: 2 different things you are talking about here :
- If you want know whats the type at runtime, then use List<object>, but i don't know how will u access objects unless by using reflection(which is not the right thing to do).



- BUT, If you know the object type and compile time(while you're writing the code), and it differs from one project to another, then using generic constraints is the right thing

Comment: @RobertBurke i'll check your question edit now, am sorry i didn't see it before

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using a `List<object>`, it might help to make your interface generic:

```
public interface MyInterface<T>
{
  Dictionary<string, List<T>> FilterLists { get; set; }
}
```