# How to create an unitialized variable to return linq result?

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

Let's say I have a drop down list in my view. Different selection will use different linq result which needed to return back to the view.

I have already got the view page done. Now at my controller, I am a bit stuck.
I know var cannot be used as uninitialized variable declaration. But how do I go about it then?

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(string Linq)
    {
        IEnumerable<NorthwindResult> Linq1;

        switch (Linq)
        {                
            case "Most Expensive":
                Linq1 = from Products in northwindEntities.Products
                            where
                              Products.UnitPrice ==
                                (from Products0 in northwindEntities.Products
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Products0.UnitPrice
                                 }).Max(p => p.UnitPrice)
                            select new NorthwindResult
                            {
                                ProductName = Products.ProductName,
                                UnitPrice = Products.UnitPrice
                            };

                break;
            case "Above Average":
                Linq1 = from Products in northwindEntities.Products
                            where
                              Products.UnitPrice >
                                (from Products0 in northwindEntities.Products
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Products0.UnitPrice
                                 }).Average(p => p.UnitPrice)
                            orderby Products.UnitPrice descending
                            select new NorthwindResult
                            {
                                ProductName = Products.ProductName,
                                UnitPrice = Products.UnitPrice
                            };
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return Linq1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. There are multiple options. Either use `dynamic` or return an object. eg. e.g. `IEnumerable<object>`, `IList<object>`. Or you can create a Product model with ProductName and UnitPrice as poco.

**Edit:**

This one is hacky but can be used.

```
void GetObject<T>(object anonymousObject, T cast)
{
   return (T) anonymousObject;
}
```

On your model, you can call like:

```
object linqResult;
// retrieve linqResult data;
....
var obj = GetObject(linqResult, new  { ProductName = "Honda", UnitPrice = 20.0 };

This variable can be accessed as 
Console.WriteLine(obj.ProductName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a custom type to use instead of the anonymous type:

```
public class ProductPrice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get;  set; }
}
```

Then `LinqResult` is declared as

```
IEnumarable<ProductPrice> LinqResult;
```

and you change the `select` to

```
select new ProductPrice { Name = Products.Product name,  Price = Products.UnitPrice };
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but when I return LinqResult, it says 'Unused of unassigned local variable LinqResult'. I have updated my latest code at the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If that really is your entire action, then you don't need to. Just replace the `LinqResult =` with `return`.

But if you ever do really need to figure out the type, I will usually temporarily declare the variable where I set it:

```
var LinqResult = from ...
```

Then, in Visual Studio, hover the cursor over the variable name, and it will tell me the type. Then I change the code and declare the variable with the type.

In this specific case it'll end up being an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type, which I don't think you can actually declare, at least not in a straight-forward way. There is some discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327594/declaration-of-anonymous-types-list).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do anything with the variable after the switch block I would just return from inside the switch block, e.g.

```
switch (Linq)
{                
        case "Most Expensive":
            return from Products in northwindEntities.Products
                        ...
        case "Above Average":
            return from Products in northwindEntities.Products
                        ....
}
return null;
```

Otherwise, you must define a type when you declare the variable unless compiler can figure the type from assignment.

You might want to use `List<object>` | `IEnumerable<object>` | `IEnumerable<dynamic>` or define the result type.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same issue, and here is the solution I found:

Put the following line in global section of your main class:

**System.Linq.IQueryable<tablename> queryname;**

This defines the query table variable (queryname), that can now be accessed anywhere within your code. You can also set up your data base reference as a Global:

**DataContext db = new DataContext(SQLConnectionString);**

"db" is now available anywhere throughout your code.

When you want to read in the table contents, you simply do this:

**queryname = from x in db.tablename select x;**

This will read the entire contents of "tablename" into your "queryname" query table.

90% of the effort in using Globals is to find the right variable type to declare. One trick I use is to define the variable locally using "var", and then add it as a watch variable in the debugger. You can then go to the watch window and it will show the exact variable type designation to use.

Comment: What is a "global section" of a class? The trouble with this question and answers is the use of poorly defined terminology. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: I'm kind of old school when it comes to programming; dating back to using FORTRAN in the 1960's. I call it the Global section, but I'm sure it has another more accepted and formal name.

Comment: Sorry, I ran into an editing timeout. The questioner specifically referred to "Global", and his intent was just to find a way to do what he wants, and have the result available outside the local scope of his routine. I attempted to answer the question in the sprit it was asked. Too often, IMO, people who ask a simple, but imprecise, question end up with posters begging the question rather than just helping the author with a simple and direct answer in the spirt it was asked. I'll be more careful and precise in any future posts. You can delete or edit this if you deem it inappropriate.

Comment: It's just that helping someone to use more precise terminology is better than to try and answer in the same style. For the rest IMO it's all a question of opinion.