# How to replace annonymous type to explicit type in C#

Tags: c#, linq, types

I have the following code:

```
var rx = table.AsEnumerable()
              .Select((row, i) => new { Row = row, Index = i })
              .Where(x => x.Row[e.ColumnIndex].ToString().ToUpper() == co)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

The type of `rx` is:

```
<>f_AnonymousType()<System.Data.DataRow,int>
```

And it works, but I need to initialize variable `rx` because it should be different in some conditions 
so my question is how to replace this var to explicit type

Comment: Create a class with a System.Data.DataRow property named Row and an int property named Index, then instantiate and populate that instead.

Comment: create a class.

Comment: Maybe, before the `FirstOrdefault()` try to `Select(e => new MyType{Prop1 = Row, prop2 = Index}).FirstOrDefault();` or, if possible you could do this in the first `Select`

Comment: So you want a datarow and it's index, if found? `because it should be different in some conditions` and how is this, it would be helpful for you to explain further details about your expected output... If output is going to be different from the statement you would still have to do a type check somewhere I would assume. You could however create an extension and pass the type you want and pass this back?

Comment: output whill be the same but x.Row[e.ColumnIndex] can be string, number or date so where clause should be different for any type

Comment: Do you want to create an instance of list to hold future possible entries? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708589/1997232).

Comment: ...Which is why it's an `object`, and also why it has the `Field<T>` extension method. However your last comment doesn't really make your question clearer, I'm afraid.

Comment: Since you are doing Linq to objects here (not to SQL) you can just take KeyValuePair<System.Data.DataRow,int> or Tuple<System.Data.DataRow,int> depending if you prefer a struct or a class.
You literally ask, how to replace it ? The name goes here `new { Row = row, Index = i }` behind the new. And you can use other constructors on your own class, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that C# generates what jon skeet refers to as an "unspeakable name"... a name that is valid in IL (C#'s compiled intermediate language and the language .net framework and .net core actually consume) but invalid in C#.

Two things

1. While these names are "unspeakable" they are predictable. You should likely *not do this under any circumstances ever* but the following works:

```cs
var nums = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
var strs = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

var query = 
  from num in nums
  from str in strs
  select new { num, str };

var list = query.ToList()

list.Add(new { num = 200, str = "anything" });
```

2. I would use the new C# tuple syntax for this, or just declare a class for it. Declaring a class obviously is the most standard but I personally am not offended by the tuple version since C# has made tuples a bit nicer....

Tuple version:

```cs
var rx = table.AsEnumerable()
              .Select((row, i) => (row, index: i))
              .Where(x => x.row[e.ColumnIndex].ToString().ToUpper() == co)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Your type in this version is going to be `IEnumerable<Tuple<DataRow, int>>` (it'll be an uglier name, but thats the gist of it), which you can obviously use a lot more easily than the anonymous type equivalent... if you had a list of those you can just `list.Add((row, index));`